# github labels api doesn't list all the labels in my repository

Tags: curl, github

I've created around 47 labels in my github repository. But when I tried to list the labels using `curl` (github api), I get only 30 labels.  Adding `&per_page=100` doesn't seem to be working in this case. Is there any solution to list all the labels ?

Appreciate your help. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use pagination to traverse pst the first page of results.  Check out https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/  , especially this point:

> For technical reasons, not every endpoint behaves the same. For
>   example, events won't let you set a maximum for items to receive. Be
>   sure to read the documentation on how to handle paginated results for
>   specific endpoints.

Especially on that page, also look under the heading "*Navigating through the pages*"
 though in your case, I would jump to page 2, not 14 like in the example.